# How to create a DynamoDB entry from F#?

Tags: f#, amazon-dynamodb

There is the following code on the AWS documentation page (I simplified):

```
Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, "ProductCatalog");
var book = new Document();
book["Id"] = 101;
book["Title"] = "Book 101 Title";
book["ISBN"] = "11-11-11-11";
table.PutItem(book);
```

When I try to the same from Fsharp I get an error:

```
let seqNumberDocument = Document()
seqNumberDocument.["key"] <- 101
```

> Type constraint mismatch. The type 
>       'int'     is not compatible with type
>       'DynamoDBEntry'

Is there a way to get this working in Fsharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call the implicit conversion to `DynamoDBEntry` like this:

```
let seqNumberDocument = Document()
seqNumberDocument.["key"] <- DynamoDBEntry.op_Implicit 101
```

F# doesn't itself support implicit conversion by design.

If that looks a bit ugly, you can use the alternative:

```
let v2 = DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2

let seqNumberDocument = Document()
seqNumberDocument.["key"] <- v2.ConvertToEntry 101
```